# Check this requirement, let me know which Magento Product Type is it?

Tags: php, e-commerce, opencart, magento

I'm new to Magento, just finished reading 2 Ebooks.  Please check the project requirement below and let me know which Product type is it and what should I have do to achieve the requirement below?

The site is going to sell only one product, that is a **Bicycle**.

**1st Tab** (Three Options) : Green cycle($30), Red Cycle($35) and Pink Cycle($33).  User can select anyone cycle from it.

**2nd Tab** - 
Three sizes of cycle has to be shown (SMALL,MEDIUM,LARGE).  Color of the cycle is based on the previous selection.  User can select anyone from it.

**3rd Tab** : 
Have to show **50 type** of Tires (if Green cycle is the selection).
Have to show **30 Type** of Tires (if Red cycle is the selection)
Have to show **40 Type** of Tires (if Pink cycle is the selection)
Price of the tires are different.  User can select anyone of the tire from it.

**4th Tab** :
Have to show 5 type of helmets here.  Price of the helmets are different.  User can select anyone from it.
Note : ***This tab should be hidden***, when a green cycle is selected.  ***Helmets are available only for Red and Pink cycles***.

Please let me know, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I've never worked with Magento, but looking at the following link:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/modules_reference/english/mage_adminhtml/catalog_product/producttype

It looks like you want the "Bundle" option. If I interpreted your question correctly, you want to only sell **one** product with different **attributes** - such as tires, helmets, size of bicycle.

Quote from the Magneto Wiki:

> This product type is also known as a “kit” in other eCommerce software. This product type is ideal for circumstances where the user have to select a number of configurable options

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for a **configurable product**, it is somewhat complex to set one up. 
Look at this link and it will explain it to you in detail.
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-configurable-product/