# Magento - How to load a set of products below, based on product selection?

Tags: magento, e-commerce, magento-1.4, magento-1.5

I have to develop a shopping site in Magento, it will have 5 tabs.

**In the first tab**, I have to display 10 different products.
Based on the selection in first tab, I have to display another set of products in the second tab.

Likewise, other 3 tabs will display related products based on previous tab's selection.

> 1. Each tab will have more than 10 products
> 2. User should at least select 1 product from each tab.

Please let me know, how to achieve this?  Expecting help from Magento experts.

Comment: This questions is likely too broad. You will need to do some work on your own and ask more focused questions here.

Comment: @benmarks Please check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11741634/check-this-requirement-let-me-know-which-magento-product-type-is-it)  for brief question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make 5 tabs in HTML, write a functionality to get all the products in first tab (other 4 tabs empty) when the page loads. When user selects a product in the first tab, fire an ajax call which will bring data and fill the second tab. Likewise, when user selected product from 2nd tab, fire ajax which brings data and fills the 3rd tab, and same goes for 4th and 5th tab.

So, finally, you will have to fire 4 ajax calls for reaching to the final tab. Now, you can just write one function only where you can pass the parameter with some `product ID` and `step number`, so that you can narrow down the filteration based on step numbers criteria.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  How to write functionality?  I'm new to Magento, but I have handful experience in PHP, MVC & Frameworks.  Please let me know some good tutorials to write custom code in Magento?  Can you give me a rough flow chart to achieve this, so that I can follow that and finish this.

Comment: Yeah sure. Basically you would need to write a new `module` with one `config.xml` and `controller`, where you will write your `action` (action is nothing but method/function). In this action you will handle your ajax request and return output. Something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835146/using-basic-ajax-calls-within-magento could help. For nice tutorial, navigate to http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-3-magento-controller-dispatch/

Comment: Thanks a lot Kalpesh.  Happy to receive such a good support.  I'll try this, will contact you if I have any trouble in implementing.

Comment: Can you check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11741634/check-this-requirement-let-me-know-which-magento-product-type-is-it) and give me a step by step answer for it?